# How to get number of mismatch between two categorical vectors

Tags: r

Good afternoon ,

Assume we have the following dataset :

```
data_cat=structure(list(c("X266", "B7", "T133", "J34", "T218", "X249"), 
    c("TVGUIDE", "MODMAT", "MASSEY", "KMART", "MASSEY", "ROSES"
    ), c("YES", "YES", "YES", "NO", "YES", "NO"), c("KEY", "KEY", 
    "KEY", "KEY", "KEY", "KEY"), c("YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", 
    "YES", "YES"), c("BENTON", "BENTON", "BENTON", "BENTON", 
    "BENTON", "BENTON"), c("GALLATIN", "GALLATIN", "GALLATIN", 
    "GALLATIN", "GALLATIN", "GALLATIN"), c("UNCOATED", "UNCOATED", 
    "UNCOATED", "UNCOATED", "UNCOATED", "COATED"), c("UNCOATED", 
    "COATED", "UNCOATED", "COATED", "UNCOATED", "COATED"), c("NO", 
    "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO"), c("LINE", "LINE", "LINE", 
    "LINE", "LINE", "LINE"), c("YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", 
    "YES"), c("Motter94", "WoodHoe70", "WoodHoe70", "WoodHoe70", 
    "WoodHoe70", "Motter94"), c("TABLOID", "CATALOG", "CATALOG", 
    "TABLOID", "CATALOG", "TABLOID"), c("NorthUS", "NorthUS", 
    "NorthUS", NA, "NorthUS", "CANADIAN"), c("noband", "noband", 
    "noband", "noband", "noband", "noband")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to calculate number of mismatch (elements that differs ) between two rows / vectors. For this i developped the following function :

```
char_dist_pairs<-function(x,y){
  
  length_charachter_part=length(which(sapply(x,class)=="factor"|sapply(x,class)=="character"|sapply(x,class)=="logical"))
  
  
  
  m=length_charachter_part-as.numeric(table(x==y)["TRUE"])
  
  m=replace(m,is.na(m),0)
  
  return(m)
}
```

This function works with another dataset as expected :

```
ballons=structure(list(YELLOW = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("PURPLE", 
"YELLOW"), class = "factor"), SMALL = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("LARGE", "SMALL"), class = "factor"), STRETCH = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("DIP", "STRETCH"), class = "factor"), ADULT = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("ADULT", "CHILD"), class = "factor"), T = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))

char_dist_pairs(ballons[1,],ballons[2,])
#output :
2
```

This is right because the `fourth` and `fifth` elements are different for the two vectors :

```
> ballons[1,]
1 YELLOW SMALL STRETCH ADULT TRUE
> ballons[2,]
2 YELLOW SMALL STRETCH CHILD FALSE
```

However i'm unable to get the expected output for the first dataset :

```
char_dist_pairs(data_cat[1,],data_cat[2,])
[1] 0
```

Here normally i should get 5 instead of 0 . I also noticed that :

```
> data_cat[1,]==data_cat[2,]
1

> ballons[1,]==ballons[2,]
  
1   TRUE  TRUE    TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

This means i can't do a logical comparison for the first dataset.

Thank you for help !

Comment: Your datasets have differnt type i.e. `factor` vs `character` difference in columns

Comment: For me , all that this not a number is qualitative variable. I think we cannot do a logical comparison between two dataframes ( class(data_cat[1,]) [1] "data.frame" )

Comment: Also, I noticed in your function, you are  calling this `sapply(x,class)` multiple times.  Instead, can create an object and reuse it

Comment: ballons[1,]==ballons[2,]
  YELLOW SMALL STRETCH ADULT     T
1   TRUE  TRUE    TRUE FALSE FALSE

Comment: data_cat[1,]==data_cat[2,]
 
1

Comment: This means i can't even do a logical comparison for the first dataset

Comment: Have you noticed that there is a logical column at the end in ballons

Comment: Yes , i noticed that ! I used |sapply(x,class)=="logical"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could modify the function to compare by `unlist`ing the `list` elements after converting the `factor` columns to `character` class

```
char_dist_pairs<-function(x, y){
  
  i <- sapply(x, is.factor)
  x[i] <- lapply(x[i], as.character)
  j <- sapply(y, is.factor)
  y[j] <- lapply(y[j], as.character)
  i1 <- sapply(x, class)
  length_charachter_part <- length(which(i1 %in%
                   c("factor", "character", "logical")))
  

  
   new <- as.numeric(table(unlist(x) == unlist(y))['TRUE'])
   
  
   m <- length_charachter_part - new
  
  
   m <- replace(m,is.na(m),0)
  
  return(m)
  
  }
```

-testing

```
char_dist_pairs(ballons[1,],ballons[2,])
#[1] 2
  
 char_dist_pairs(data_cat[1,],data_cat[2,])
#[1] 5
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your precious help !

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the anti_join function in dplyr.

```
mismatched_rows <-anti_join(x,y, by = c(t = t))
nrow(mismatched_rows)
```

Comment: your solution isn't working. Error: join columns must be character vectors.